# JavaFX's controller is different from the MVC's controller?

Tags: javafx

I'm studying JavaFX and MVC pattern. Since MVC is a pattern which has many different interpretations, i still have to fully comprehend what's going on. But one thing has always bothered me.

In the MVC pattern, i understood that the View has a specific role: containing all the elements (buttons, textfield, ...) and handling the events (so, methods like 'X_Button_Clicked()'), while the Controller should deal with business logic (what must happen when you click the button?). Or, at least, that's what my university taught me.

But using JavaFX has made me more confused than ever. My program has a View which simply loads the FXML file (so, just a start() method, and a 'loadXClass()' method), while the JavaFX's controller contains the buttons and the event handlers... which is not quite an MVC pattern. I notice that this way of structuring the code goes totally against the benefits of using an MVC pattern: the controller contains buttons, event handling... and business logic?

So i started researching online and i found something that, if it's true, totally changes my mind on what i did until now: what is called 'Controller' in JavaFX is **actually** the View.

This would make so much sense. But i'm not too sure. Did i get it right? And if I did... could i implement what i used to call 'View' inside the 'JavaFX controller?'. Or else, should i move the 'load FXML file' inside JavaFX's controller', and the business logic which was previously inside 'JavaFX's controller' inside a newly created ACTUAL controller?

Comment: MVC is not a very clearly defined pattern and you will find many different interpretations of it. A good resource that looks at the different ways it is interpreted is the [Martin Fowler article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) (now quite old). I think of the FXML "controller" as being closer to a "presenter" in the sense of the MVP pattern (particularly the "passive view" variation of it). Swing's controls use a "UI delegate" which (loosely?) combines the view and controller in a single object. You can also think of the FXML and the controller combining to make a "UI delegate".

Comment: *"could i implement what i used to call 'View' inside the 'JavaFX controller?'"* Assuming you are still using FXML,  the FXML would still perform the layout, which is very much part of the job of the View. *"Or else, should i move the 'load FXML file' inside JavaFX's controller',"* I would not recommend this. However, check out the [custom component pattern](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) which does use this approach.

Comment: *"the business logic which was previously inside 'JavaFX's controller' "*. A controller should typically contain "view logic", not "business logic". A large-scale application will have multiple tiers (typically the presentation tier, business logic tier, data access tier, persistence tier, etc.). All of MVC, including the model, is part of the presentation tier. The business logic is part of another tier entirely.

Comment: See also [_Application Structure: The MVVM Pattern_](https://fxdocs.github.io/docs/html5/#_application_structure).

Comment: I suggest reading Martin Fowler's article on [UI architectures](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

Comment: Martin Fowler is a great resource.  I don't think that MVC is "not a very clearly defined pattern".  It's very clearly defined, but very poorly understood.  In MVC the View should be a complete unit as described by the OP, and should keep it's inner workings to itself.  An FXML file isn't complete by itself, and it doesn't keep its secrets either, as evidenced by all those @FXML statements in the FXML Controller.  So it cannot be considered an MVC View.  The FXML File + FXML Controller + FXMLLoader can be considered to be the View.  You have to build your own MVC Controller and Model.

Comment: @James_D in MVC, the Model is supposed to have the business logic for whatever function that MVC serves.  In that respect it is considered isolated from the Presentation Layer, with the understanding that it also contains, observes and updates  the Presentation Model which is used directly in the Presentation Layer.

Comment: I learned a lot about these issues when I started to use https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX and read more about MVVM. I too think indeed that the name JavaFX controller is misleading and therefore other people call it "the code behind" and it actually could be considered being a part of the view.

Comment: I recall some comments by the original FXML author that the whole FXML setup and architecture of the FXML system, in particular what the Controller was and how it might be used, was deliberately architecturally vague and unspecified.  Kind of like an anti-rails, more an open road (my analogy).  The idea being that users could make of it what they wanted. If they wanted to put lots of business logic in the controller, then go ahead.  If they wanted to keep it strictly view related and architecturally separate logic elsewhere, then fine.

Comment: The point being that the JavaFX library support is mostly architecture agnostic and users  can choose to apply in their own code or higher level frameworks conformance to the kind of architecture they prefer.  Nowhere is it written that an FXML controller must be a C in an MVC design, though many interpret it that way, given the name.

Comment: @jewelsea I think the name "Controller" is most unfortunate.  "Presenter" would have been much, much better as people would have interpreted it as an implementation of MVP which you can actually do with FXML.

Comment: Thanks to everyone of you for your answer. You really shed light on my doubts!